# How to limit a jQuery plugin function to only some elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I check the jQuery plugin site, which teach me how to write a basic plugin:

```
(function( $ ){
  $.fn.maxHeight = function() {
    var max = 0;
    this.each(function() {
      max = Math.max( max, $(this).height() );
    });
    return max;
  };
})( jQuery );
```

Then, the div can have the `maxHeight` method, like this:

```
var tallest = $('div').maxHeight(); // Returns the height of the tallest div
```

But I would like to only textarea have maxHeight function, but not the div. How can I do so?

Comment: What do you want to happen when you try and use it on a div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to make sure the element is a textarea before checking/saving the height.

```
this.each(function() {
    if(this.tagName.toLowerCase() === "textarea") {
        max = Math.max( max, $(this).height() );
    }
});
```

jQuery plugins don't give functions to certain elements, they give functions to the jQuery object for working with a set of selected elements.  The best solution would be to keep them as generic as possible and only call `$("textarea").maxHeight()` when you need it.  You aren't doing anything specific to `textarea`s in the plugin and if you leave it as it is now, you don't need to make a change to it in the future if `$('div').maxHeight()` becomes a required use-case.

Comment: You can use `is('textarea')`.

Comment: This is the same thing, but without the overhead of the Sizzle parser.

Answer (score 1):

You could do...

```
this.filter('textarea')
```

If you do an `each()` on the returned set, it will only iterate over selected `textarea` elements.