# jquery plugin on a specific element

Tags: jquery

Is there any way that I can define jquery plugin for a particular element? like the way javascript provide?

For example,
In javascript, I can do like this

```
HTMLSelectElement.prototype.loadData = function () {
    //do something
};
```

With this I can use `loadData` function on `select`, how can I do this with jQuery?

I know about this,

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.loadData = function () {
        //do something
    };
}(jQuery));
```

But, how to ensure that the element which I am using this plugin on is a `select` element not other elements?

Comment: select the element via $('#YourItemID').yourfunction();

Comment: @brandelizer how do I prevent the use of this plugin on other elements?

Comment: you can take 'css selectors' like :first-of-type or others... or you choose an unique id for that element

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: @brandelizer that's not the problem, how to make this plugin appear only on selecting a correct element? for example, I want this function to appear  for `select` element only, not for `div`

Comment: $('select').yourfunction();

Comment: @brandelizer this function still executes on `$('div').loadData()` which I don't want to work

Comment: oh... you want to make an own function and check in the function if its a select or not? So you can check in your function $(this).prop("tagName").toLowerCase(); and check the tag name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit a jQuery plugin function to only some elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519637/how-to-limit-a-jquery-plugin-function-to-only-some-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stop it when the function begins:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.loadData = function () {
        var index = 0, $this = $(this), length = $this.length;
        for ( ; index < length; index++) {
            var current = $this[index];
            if (!$(current).is('select')) {
                return;
            }
        }
        // do something
    };
}(jQuery));
```

EDIT: Updated to handle calling plugin on multiple elements. Thanks Felix!

Comment: Worth pointing out that `.is` returns `true` if *at least one* element matches.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks! Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .is() (http://api.jquery.com/is/) to test if $(this) is a select element inside your function.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.loadData = function () {
        if (!$(this).is('select')){
            return;
        }
    };
}(jQuery));
```