# How to use jquery callback functions in if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have a function whinch performs something and it works great. Now i want to add a bootstrap modal and execute the same code when modal closes. But my problem is that i have to check for user status. Is there a way how to execute this code and not to copy everything twice?

```
if(USERTYPE == 0) {
  $("#fastRegisterModal").modal('show');
  $("#fastRegisterModal").on('hidden', function() {
    //Code for registration and upload code
  }
} else {
  //upload code
}
```

I want to include this into multiple jquery function (mostly .live functions) and i don't want to move "upload code" into normal js function (I got the .js file writen as it is and i don't want to change 70% of the file)

Is this even possible in this or any other way?

### EDITED

Here is some more code:

```
$('.someAction').live('click', function(event) {
// Init section
var data1 = $(".getData1").val();
var data2 = $(".getData2").val();

// I want to add this modal check before exsisting code

if(USERTYPE == 0) {
    $("#fastRegisterModal").modal('show').on('hidden', function() {
        var email = $(".getModalEmail").val();
        var pass = $(".getModalPass").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "actions/fastRegister",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {email: email, pass: pass}, 
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.success == 1) {
                    // continue with existing block of code
                }
            }
        });
    });
}

// Existing block of code

$.ajax({
    url: "actions/someAction",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {data1: data1, data2: data2}, 
    success: function(data) {
        if (data != '') {
            // show success
        }
    }
});
});
```

I hope this explaings my situation bether :)

Comment: Can you show more code. It doesn't make sense why you don't want to use a "normal" js function.

Comment: your not providing enough code

Comment: For me, create a function is the only way to call the same code in multiple function... Maybe you prefer to create a new jQuery method? Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709822/add-jquery-function-to-specific-elements

Comment: @popnoodles, the up&down votes here are weird. Maybe I'm missing something here though.

Comment: I have added some more code. I hope it explains my situation better.

Comment: You haven't explained why you see the refactoring into a function to be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the function.

How much more work is it than two lines of code and a cut and paste?

Resisting refactoring tends to lead to long term pain.

Doesn't something like this work? How much effort is it to get there from what you have?

```
var doSomeAction = function () {
    $.ajax({
          url: "actions/someAction",
          type: 'POST',
          data: {data1: data1, data2: data2}, 
          success: function(data) {
              if (data != '') {
                // show success
              }
          }
     });

 };

 if(USERTYPE == 0) {
    $("#fastRegisterModal").modal('show').on('hidden', function() {
       var email = $(".getModalEmail").val();
       var pass = $(".getModalPass").val();

       $.ajax({
          url: "actions/fastRegister",
          type: 'POST',
          data: {email: email, pass: pass}, 
         success: function(data) {
            if (data.success == 1) {
                doSomeAction();
            }
          }
      });
    });
} else {
   doSomeAction();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So let's assume **there's a good reason** that you don't want to write a "normal" js function.

You could extend jQuery.

```
$.fn.extend({
    doSomething: function(){
        // do something with $(this)
    }
});

and then

if(USERTYPE == 0) {
  $("#fastRegisterModal").modal('show').on('hidden', function() {
    $(this).doSomething();
  }
} else {
  $("#fastRegisterModal").doSomething();
}
```

Or you can create a custom bind and trigger it.

```
$("#fastRegisterModal").on('doSomething', function(){
     // do something with $(this)
});

if(USERTYPE == 0) {
  $("#fastRegisterModal").modal('show').on('hidden', function() {
    $(this).trigger('doSomething');
  }
} else {
  $("#fastRegisterModal").trigger('doSomething');
}
```

The comments in your code show two different things want to happen

```
if(USERTYPE == 0) {
  $("#fastRegisterModal").modal('show');
  $("#fastRegisterModal").on('hidden', function() {
    //Code for registration and upload code
    $(this).trigger('doRegistration').trigger('doUpload');
    // or $(this).doRegistration().doUpload();
  }
} else {
    //upload code
    $(this).trigger('doUpload');
    // or $(this).doUpload();
}
```

Comment: But he's still creating a function and moving his code into it?

Comment: With the small amount of code given this MAY be appropriate. Avoiding copy-paste which is paramount, these two options are the only alternatives (that I know of) to creating a "normal" js function.