# Jquery overloading core function with single element

Tags: jquery, overloading

In Jquery, I would like to overloading hide method of a specific element, is it the only way I can do?

```
    var oldhide = jQuery.fn.hide;

    jQuery.fn.hide = function(){
        if($(this)===$(#myselemnt){
           //do something
        }
        oldhide .apply($(this));
    }
```

So it override all hide method with every element in the website. Can I get a better way that only modify the hide function for one element?

Comment: It would be unintuitive to have the hide() function do different things for different elements, so I'd be surprised if there was a way to do that.  Why do you want to do it this way rather than call a different function for #myselemnt in the first place?

Comment: I did make lots things for my website, and I need a special 'hide' function for the #myselemnt(misspell LOL). But there are several ways to close this element, like click the 'close' button, switch to other tab, leave the current page etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I messed around for a bit, and couldn't get it to work.  This is the best answer I could find:

[Add jQuery function to specific elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709822/add-jquery-function-to-specific-elements)

Your first solution is a bit of a duct tape one, but it'll work.  Other than that, you could make a function called close(), call that instead of hide(), and then within there call specific hides.  It's basically the same as your solution above, but easier to read for follow up programmers.