# Apply a function to a variable

Tags: jquery

I've searched this here, and I found a few answers but none of them worked for me.

As told in the title, I want to apply a function to a variable.

This is what I have:

```
var someVar = $('.class');

function runFunction() {
    someVar.css( ... styles here ... );
}

someVar.runFunction();
```

It only works if I replace 'someVar.runFunction();' with 'runFunction();'.

Your help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$.fn.greenify = function() {
    this.css( "color", "green" );
};

$( "a" ).greenify();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set it on jQuery element, you need to use:

```
$.fn.runFunction = function() {
    return this.css( ... styles here ... );
}
```

### --DEMO--

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `bind()`.

Check this similar discussion: [Add jQuery function to specific elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709822/add-jquery-function-to-specific-elements)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to use the function with a parameter, try something like this:

```
var someVar = $('.class');

function runFunction( element ) {
    element.css( ... styles here ... );
}

runFunction( someVar );
```